# how can I group on converted values?

Tags: django

so far I have this query:

```
q = Foobar.objects.values('updater','updated')
q = q.annotate(update_count=Count("id"))
```

which seems to generate a query like:

```
select updater, updated, count(id)
from foobar
group by updater, updated
```

"updated" is a date-time field, and I'd like to do my counts by day, with a query that looks like:

```
select updater, cast(updated as date), count(id)
from foobar
group by updater, cast(updated as date)
```

is there a way to do this with the Query API, or do I have to drop back to raw SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't support this level of control over database queries - generally, you can't make queries use functions like CAST.

You have a few options in this case, though. First of all, most simply, you can just take the datetime object returned by the ORM object and remove the extra precision using `datetime.replace()`.

Another option, if you know that you'll never want your Django app to use any precision in the updated field beyond the day, is to simply define `updated` in your models.py as a `models.DateField()` as opposed to `models.DateTimeField()`. This means data returned by the ORM Model will never have precision beyond the day.

Finally, I assume you're using the most recent Django (1.1), but in Django 1.2 (scheduled for May 10), you'll be able to do the following:

`Foobar.objects.raw("select updater, cast(updated as date), count(id) from foobar group by updater, cast(updated as date)")`

The result (assuming it has the same number of columns and column types as what you've defined in your Foobar model) will be a normal django ORM Queryset.

Answer (score 0):

QuerySet.dates() ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#dates-field-kind-order-asc ) takes you part of the way there, but it doesn't seem to play nice with `.values()` and make a `GROUP BY` (I tried for a few minutes).  Maybe you've already seen that anyway...

But it does show that Django already has an SQL function that you'll need if you write your own SQL version:

```
print(ProcessingState.objects.dates('timestamp', 'day').query)
```

yields

```
SELECT DISTINCT django_date_trunc("day", "databot_processingstate"."timestamp")
    FROM "databot_processingstate" ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

(sorry for the weird table names and stuff, it's just my own model I happend to have handy)